# "Best before" puzzle

Tags: c++, beginner, parsing, programming-challenge, datetime

I'm new To C++ and decided to have a go at the [Spotify challenges](https://labs.spotify.com/puzzles/) on their website.

I have now finished but I get the feeling my code is just terrible. I'm guessing it would be very hard for someone else to read and I feel like there are much better ways to code this.

Their "Best Before" puzzle asks: Given a possibly ambiguous date written in "A/B/C" format, where A,B,C are integers between 0 and 2999, interpret them as M/D/Y or D/M/Y or whatever common date format. Pick the interpretation that yields the earliest possible legal date between Jan 1, 2000 and Dec 31, 2999 (inclusive) in "YYYY-MM-DD" format.  If the string cannot be interpreted as a valid date, state so.

Here is my code for the best before puzzle:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int Year;
int Month;
int Day;




stringstream ss;
string input;
string in;
bool loop=true;
int date[4];
bool DateFound=false;


void Check_date();
void Check_date()
{


    if(DateFound==false)
    {
    //Check if valid Year
    if (date[1]<2999 && date[1]>0 && date[2]>0 && date[3]>0) 
    {   //check months & days are valid
        if(date[2]==1 || date[2]==3 || date[2]==5 || date[2]==7 || date[2]==8 || date[2]==10 || date[2]==12){if(date[3]<=31){DateFound=true;}}
        if(date[2]==4 || date[2]==6 || date[2]==9 || date[2]==11){if(date[3]<=30){DateFound=true;}}
        //Check For Leap Year
        if (date[2]==2)
        {   if(date[3]<28)DateFound=true;
            if(date[1]%4==0 && date[3]<=29)DateFound=true;
            if(date[1]%100==0 && date[1]%400!=0 && date[3]>28)DateFound=false;
        }

    }   
    if(DateFound==true){Year=date[1]; Month=date[2]; Day=date[3];if(Year<1000){Year=Year+2000;} if(Month<10){}}

    }




}





void SwitchDate(){int temp; temp=date[2]; date[2]=date[3]; date[3]=temp; Check_date();};
void ShiftDate(int places)
{   if(places==1)
    {
    int temp; temp=date[3]; date[3]=date[2]; date[2]=temp; temp=date[1]; date[1]=date[2]; date[2]=temp;  Check_date();
    }
    if(places==2)
    {
    int temp; temp=date[1]; date[1]=date[2]; date[2]=temp; temp=date[2]; date[2]=date[3]; date[3]=temp; Check_date();
    }
};

int main ()
{   
    //Main Loop
    while(loop==true)
    {

    cout <<"Please Enter a date \n";
    cin>>input;
    cout<<endl;

    for (int x=0, y=1; y<=3; y++, x++)
        {
            while (input[x] !='/' && x !=input.length()) ss<<input[x++];
            ss>> date[y];
            ss.clear();
        }

    //order small medium large
    for (int x=3, temp; x!=0; x--)
    {
        if (date[x] < date[x-1]) 
            {   temp=date[x-1];
                date[x-1]=date[x];
                date[x]=temp;
            }
        if (x==1 && (date[2] > date[3] )) 
                {
                    temp=date[3];
                    date[3]=date[2];
                    date[2]=temp;
                }

    }



    Check_date();
    SwitchDate();
    ShiftDate(1);
    SwitchDate();
    ShiftDate(2);
    SwitchDate();




    //PRINT
    if(DateFound==true)
    {
    cout <<"The smallest valid date is: "; 
    cout <<setw(2)<<setfill('0')<<Year; cout<<"-";
    cout <<setw(2)<<setfill('0')<<Month; cout<<"-" ;
    cout <<setw(2)<<setfill('0')<<Day;
    cout<<endl;
    }
    else cout<<date[1]<<"/"<<date[2]<<"/"<<date[3]<<" Is illegal \n";






    DateFound=false;
    cout <<"Again? 'Y' or 'N' \n";
    cin >>in;
    cout << endl;
    if(in=="y" || in=="Y"){loop=true;}
    if(in=="n" || in=="N"){loop=false;}
    }//End of Loop
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You should avoid using global variables. If you import this code into a future project it might cause problems -- name conflicts etc.

   If you must do this, put them in an anonymous namespace so that they're only in scope for this file:

   ```
   namespace
   {
       int my;
       int globals;
       int defined;
       int here;
   }
   ```
2. The declaration of `Check_date()` is not necessary here:

   ```
   void Check_date();
   void Check_date()
   {
   ```
3. This could perhaps written better:

   ```
   for (int x=0, y=1; y<=3; y++, x++)
   {
       while (input[x] !='/' && x !=input.length()) ss<<input[x++];
       ss>> date[y];
       ss.clear();
   }
   ```

   There is little point using x in the for loop as you don't have an exit condition for it. Also, I would prefer a more meaningful name.

   Instead, perhaps:

   ```
   int inputPos = 0;
   for(int dateIndex = 1; dateIndex <= 3; ++dateIndex)
   {
       while(input[inputPos] != '/' && inputPos != input.length()) 
       {
           ss >> date[dateIndex];
           ss.clear();
       }
       ++inputPos;
   }
   ```
4. More generally you've written this in a very C-like style -- I would have defined a type (class) for `Date`, which would have month and day members. Then the logic for whether month lengths are valid can be encapsulated properly.

   You could also encapsulate the read-from-stream code using an [iostreams extractor](http://www.cplusplus.com/istream::operator%3E%3E).